# How to get only source files from WSDL file using wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

When i tried to use `wsimport http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL` the command generate .class files only.

and when i tried to use `wsimport -keep -s directory http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL` the command generate .class files and .java files.
is there any parameter to generate .java files only .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use -Xnocompile flag

```
wsimport -keep -Xnocompile http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL
```

Answer (score 0):

it is in help output of `wsimport -h`, in Extensions part.

> Extensions: 
> ...... 
> `-Xnocompile                     do not compile generated Java files`